# I'm confused about Logical Operators, can someone help me clear up my mess? Multiple arguments?

Tags: java, operators, logic

this is my first post here, but I often use this site to help me with coding issues I run into. I'm an intermediate level Java programmer. I'm going to college next year and I'm considering a minor in Computer Science.

I'm making a pretty basic mock-credit card validator that reads in a credit card, checks if it's valid, and then emails information to the user. This is not to be used for anything other than educational purposes.

So I have a bit of code that checks multiple conditions for a credit card string that someone types in. For example, as you'll see, it checks the starting digit, the name of the card, and the number of digits. It checks the conditions, and if they are met the program continues, if not it gives an error and stops immediately. I'm like 99% sure that I'm entering my information in correctly, but it gives me the error no matter what and I'm at a loss here.

Sorry if I typed so much, again I'm new here. So I'm asking for help on my logic here, thanks!

```
 if((cardType.equals("Visa") && card.substring(0).equals("4")) && (length == 13 || length == 16)){
  System.out.println("Thank you, next step");
  cardValid = true;
  }
if((cardType.equals("Master Card")) && (card.substring(0,1).equals("51") || card.substring(0,1).equals("52") || card.substring(0,1).equals("53") || card.substring(0,1).equals("54") || card.substring(0,1).equals("55")) && (length == 16)){
  System.out.println("Thank you, next step");
  cardValid = true;
  }
if((cardType.equals("American Express") && card.substring(0,1).equals("37") && length == 15)){
     System.out.println("Thank you, next step");
     cardValid = true;
     }

  if(cardValid != true){
  System.out.println("ERROR");
  System.exit(0);
  }
  }
```

Comment: I can add the rest of my code if you'd like, it's about 300 lines. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that `if(cardValid != true)` can be equivalently written as `if (!cardValid)`. rgettman has the answer to your question, though.

Comment: Just a point of efficiency, don't substring your card each time. Create a new string with first two characters in:

String cardStart = card.substring(0, 2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the `substring` method correctly.  To get the first character as a substring, you need to use [the two-argument version of `substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), to supply a beginning index (inclusive) and an ending index (exclusive).

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
>
> endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.

(The [one-argument version of `substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) takes a substring from the given index through the rest of the string.)

> The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.

Replace

```
card.substring(0).equals("4")
```

with

```
card.substring(0, 1).equals("4")
```

or just compare the character there.

```
card.charAt(0) == '4'
```

Next, to get the first two characters, again take into account the fact that the ending index is exclusive.  Replace

```
card.substring(0,1).equals("37")
```

with

```
card.substring(0,2).equals("37")
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.
You had some syntactic errors with String.substring. You can refer to a full list of String functions in the java documentation below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
  if((cardType.equals("Visa") && card.substring(0,1).equals("4")) && (length == 13 || length == 16)){
  System.out.println("Thank you, next step");
  cardValid = true;
  }
if((cardType.equals("Master Card")) && (card.substring(0,2).equals("51") || card.substring(0,2).equals("52") || card.substring(0,2).equals("53") || card.substring(0,2).equals("54") || card.substring(0,2).equals("55")) && (length == 16)){
  System.out.println("Thank you, next step");
  cardValid = true;
  }
if((cardType.equals("American Express") && card.substring(0,2).equals("37") && length == 15)){
     System.out.println("Thank you, next step");
     cardValid = true;
     }

  if(!cardValid){
  System.out.println("ERROR");
  System.exit(0);
  }
  }
```